# Cannot use shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: modifiers

When I import an STL file and try to use the shrinkwrap modifier, I cannot set the target to be the body. Whenever I click the eyedropper and click on the object, it says "failed to set value". Could anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see from the screenshot, you have no object other than the teeth, so it would seem you're trying to shrinkwrap them onto themselves. And a quick test gave me exactly that error when I tried to shrinkwrap an object onto itself.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Ah yes! Thank you so much. I mistakenly thought there would be another automatically created object to shrink wrap the target, and after a second thought I was totally wrong. This makes much more sense!